# Modx pthumb how to display image height properly

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, phpthumb, modx-templates

i've tried to ouput this in a chunk :

```
[[pthumb? &input=`[[+image]]` &options=`w=320` &toPlaceholder=`thumb`]]
[[+thumb.height]]`
```

It displays only once if I refresh the page, it does not appear anymore.

Question is there a solid way to display the height of a resized image (with pthumb, phpthumbup or phpthumbof?

Answer (score 0):

Your call pthumb is cached, so it properly display only once, if you need to get height placeholder all time - so call snippet not cached (with !) -

```
[[!pthumb? &input=`[[+image]]` &options=`w=320` &toPlaceholder=`thumb`]]
[[+thumb.height]]`
```